# If we block our site to certain countries, will it damage our SE ranking?

Tags: seo, pagerank

There are certain countries which our site is not relevant for, due to language , payment and other considerations.

Will it damage our SE ranking to block these countries?

Currently we get 30-40% non-relevant traffic and we pay unnecessary fees for that.

Comment: AFAIK It will not harm you if you set the preferred Geo Location  in Webmaster Tools and please mention the method you used to do that

Comment: Maybe backtrack **why** you get that much traffic, and fix it. Could be spambots or brutefoce attacks on your server. Those are easily blocked with a firewall (server level, not htaccess or something)

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not. If you block the unrelevant countries it should even help you to rank better in SE, because your relevant users will be a bigger part of all users and this will improve your site's behavioral factors.